# Always six of us

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle is 12 letters in total.

Here's some info:

- 2 each

---

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Always six of us'? The answer is:

> **FACES OF A CUBE**

How do we find this? Firstly:

> Piece together the 6 3x3 squares using the side letters as markers of common boundaries. Some squares will need to be rotated or flipped, but eventually we can reach the net of a cube which looks like this:
>
>  [image: Cube net by matching sides]

Next:

> Use the diagram that looks a lot like a route map with 12 stopping points. This in itself needs a little modifying before we use it, as it is currently 'folded up'. If we 'unfold' it along the lines marked in blue here:
>
>  [image: Unfold the route map]
>
>  ...then we can overlay this over our cube net to spell out a phrase using the letters marked by the 12 stopping points:
>
>  [image: Overlaying the path on the cube net]
>
>  We now see it spelling out the thematic 12-letter phrase: **FACES OF A CUBE**!

Comment: Nicely demonstrated! This is ofc the correct answer  

Comment: @shoover Sure :) rot13((v) Rnpu 'rqtr yrggre' nccrnerq rknpgyl gjvpr, fhttrfgvat gurl fubhyq or cnverq hc; (vv) V nffhzrq gur erq gvyr jnf fcrpvny naq va gur pbeerpg bevragngvba sebz gur fgneg; (vvv) V zngpurq vgf N naq S rqtrf, gura vgf U naq P rqtrf, ebgngvat gur cvrprf nf erdhverq, gura nqqrq gur ynfg 2 fdhnerf ba ivn gur Y naq R rqtrf nf orsber; (vi) Ng guvf cbvag V abgvprq fbzr syvccvat jnf erdhverq nf jryy nf ebgngvba, naq syvccrq fdhnerf hagvy gur jubyr arg zngpurq; (i) Svanyyl, nf gur cngu fgnegrq gb genpr bhg jbeqf V zbirq gur arg'f fdhnerf gb bgure cbfvgvbaf gung zngpurq gur genvy.)

Answer (score 5):

Its seem

> walking on a cube! Start from **F**

> [image]

Comment: So what is the 12-letter word? The puzzle says the answer should be 12 letters.

Comment: Rot13 - (Juvyr lbh'er pbeerpg gung guvf vf vaqrrq n phor, lbh'yy unir gb erguvax gur fgnegvat cbvag.)

Comment: lrf lbh evtug! gur pbeerpg fgneg cbvag  vf S.